# Terminate and throw errors on conditions - DB2 triggers

Tags: triggers, db2, database-trigger

I have a trigger that is running before update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER HIST_LOG_UPDT_TR 
BEFORE UPDATE ON HIST_LOG 
REFERENCING     NEW ROW AS N
            OLD ROW AS O
BEGIN
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (N.STATE_CD=2 AND O.STATE_CD=0)
        RAISE_ERROR('ERR0001', 'THIS IS AN ILLEGAL UPDATE');
    END
END
```

when creating this trigger gives below error.

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=,;RENCING NEW ROW AS N;<space>, DRIVER=3.69.24
```

though -104 code means  ILLEGAL TOKEN, I could not spot any errors.

can you experts please let me know how to get this resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raise_error is a function not a statement. Also the referencing clause syntax is slightly different than shown in your question.

If your Db2-server runs on Linux or Unix or Windows, this alternative syntax may also help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER HIST_LOG_UPDT_TR 
BEFORE UPDATE ON HIST_LOG 
REFERENCING  NEW AS N OLD AS O
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (N.STATE_CD = 2 AND O.STATE_CD = 0) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'ER001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'THIS IS AN ILLEGAL UPDATE';
    END IF;
END
```